#  use Outlook Add-In for 2003 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, office-addins

We created an Outlook add-in 2003 in Visual Studio 2008. We just moved to Visual Studio 2010. When we debug the project, it shows that required version of Office is not installed.

Is there any possible way to use the Outlook 2003 Add-In in Visual Studio 2010?

I need to work my Add-In in all versions of Outlook from 2003-2010 and I have to use Visual Studio 2010 only.

Comment: Do you have Office 2003 installed?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you should have Office 2003 installed.